# Securing PHP file. Allow variables to be posted only from HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using simple HTML/AJAX/PHP script.

```
<form id="new_user" action="" method="post">
   <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
   <label for="username">Username</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" required>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
   <label for="city">City</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" required>
   </div>
   <input type="button" name="button1" value="Done" class="btn btn-success" onClick="aa();"></button>
</form>
<div id="d1"></div>
```

When the button is clicked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function aa()
{
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST","ins.php?username="+document.getElementById("username").value+"&city="+document.getElementById("city").value,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;;

}
</script>
```

My ins.php file:

```
<?php

$username_safe = htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']);
$city_safe = htmlspecialchars($_GET['city']);

echo $username_safe . " " . $city_safe;
?>
```

How to secure the ins.php file (or even the entire form) so that the client wouldn't be able to post variables from URL field, like: http://www.example.com/ins.php?username=aaa&city=bbb

Comment: implement csrf protection using tokens...easy to research. Also use POST properly

Comment: You're sending a POST request, but putting all your parameters into the URI.

Comment: In your example.com URL, fields are not being posted and won't appear in $_POST. They will be in $_GET and $_REQUEST. Your Javascript executes a POST but adding the parameters to the URL so they appear in $_GET. You seem confused about how HTTP works. And you need to be a LOT more specific about your threat models before we can advise what would be considered secure.

Answer (score 0):

**Directly referencing your question:**

> How to secure the ins.php file (or even the entire form) so that the client wouldn't be able to post variables from URL field, like: http://www.example.com/ins.php?username=aaa&city=bbb

This is already being done as passing parameters in the URL is a GET request, you've set your form up to be a POST submitted form in the line:

```
<form id="new_user" action="" method="post">
```

So just don't look at the `$_GET` super global array. Look at `$_POST` instead. [Better yet use the `filter_input()` function correctly](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) e.g.: `$username_safe = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`

Comment: Did You mean I have to edit my `ins.php` file like that?


    `<?php

    $username_safe = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $city_safe = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'city', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    echo $username_safe . " " . $city_safe;
    ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Generate an id which is only valid for a certain amount of time (say 15 minutes). Build your form with php, and include this ID inside a `<input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>">`

Send this ID back to the server, and check in PHP if this ID is allowed to submit this form.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are sending your vars by POST vice GET, so this really shouldn't be an issue.  Barring using either of these methods, you could also send the vars as session data but this becomes cumbersome to set/unset the session vars.